# Adjusting x-axis labels in ggplot bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, axis-labels

I want to move the labels of the bars which are below mean line on the upper side.
[image]

I am using this code to make this graph

```
horiz <- mean(data$SPAD)
quux <- data %>%
  select(Genotype,Species, SPAD) %>%
  arrange(desc(SPAD)) %>%
  mutate(Genotype = factor(Genotype, levels = Genotype))

ggplot(quux, aes(Genotype, fill=Species)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=as.numeric(Genotype)-0.4, xmax=as.numeric(Genotype) + 0.4, 
                ymin=pmax(horiz, SPAD), ymax=pmin(horiz, SPAD)), colour="black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#e9002d', '#ffaa00', '#00b000','blue'))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = SPAD, 
                    ymax = ifelse(SPAD > horiz, SPAD+3.3306, pmin(horiz, SPAD-3.3306))), width = 0.4,
                position = position_dodge(0.9)) + theme_bw()+
  scale_x_discrete() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(6.8, 13.50, 0.75),labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.01))+ 
  geom_hline(yintercept = horiz, linetype = "dashed", color = "black")+
  geom_text(aes(label = Genotype, y = horiz), angle=90, hjust = 1.1) +
  labs(title="a.",y="", x="")+ theme_light()+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y =element_text(colour="black", size = "10", face = "bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.02,vjust = 1, size = "11", face = "bold"),
        legend.position=c(0.93, 0.9), legend.text = element_text(size=10,face= "italic"))
```

dataset
|Genotype|  Species|SPAD|
|:-------:|:-------:|:-----:|
|BGB003|    sp1 |35.5642|
|BGB008|    sp1 |34.8968|
|BGB009|    sp1|    32.8186|
|BGB027|    sp1|    40.6409|
|BGB045|    sp1|    32.9753|
|BGB083|    sp2|    34.1282|
|BGB086|    sp2|    33.824|
|BGB088|    sp3|    36.9244|
|BGB089|    sp3|    37.7132|
|BGB091|    sp3|    43.968|
|BGB093|    sp3|    39.1745|
|BGB096|    sp2|    32.1512|
|BGB098|    sp2|    36.8385|
|BGB101|    sp2|    42.7797|
|BGB102|    sp2|    33.7136|
|BGB103|    sp2|    40.8532|
|BGB107|    sp2|    39.5082|
|BGB109|    sp2|    49.1457|
|BGB113|    sp2|    43.1033|
|BGB313|    sp4|    44.675|
|BGB444|    sp2|    33.3934|
|BGB451|    sp2|    33.4456|
|BGB467|    sp2|    37.6576|
|BGB472|    sp2|    35.7361|

Answer (score 3):

finally, i added condition formula to `geom_text()`
like this, which enable me to move the labels

```
 geom_text(aes(label = Genotype, y = ifelse(SPAD > horiz, horiz, pmax(SPAD, horiz+7)),angle=90, hjust = 1.1)
```

[image]